# Calculate Vector of Averages for Multi-dimensional Array

Tags: c#, .net, multidimensional-array, average, accord.net

Is there a method to find average of every value across multiple arrays?
I have

```
double[][] a = new double[numDas][];
```

All I need is to get a one dimensional array back that contains averages of every index of the second dimension.  So basically if I have this

```
t[0] = new double[] { 1, 2 };
t[1] = new double[] { 3, 5 };
```

Then the output would be { 2, 3.5 }

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a C# question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `double[][]` is a [jagged array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx). You may want to use a [multi-dimensional array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) `double[,]`. Then you can use `Accord.NET` as below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[,] A = {
            {1, 2},
            {3, 5}
        };

        double[] B = Vector.Ones(2);

        Console.WriteLine("A = \n{0}", Matrix.ToString(A));
        Console.WriteLine("\nB = \n{0}", Matrix.ToString(B));
        Console.WriteLine("\nAt*B/2 = \n{0}", Matrix.ToString(A.Transpose().Dot(B).Divide(2)));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Which gives:

```
A =
1 2
3 5

B =
1 1

At*B/2 =
2 3.5
```

Comment: Thank you.  That looks like exactly what I need!

Comment: By the way, is there an Accord .NET method to convert jagged to multi dimensional?  Thanks!  If not, I will have to rework some code.

Comment: There's one to convert from multi-dimensional to jagged, `ToJagged()`. I think it wouldn't make sense to convert from jagged to multi-dimensional because multi-dimensional has the same number of columns for all rows. And jagged, by definition, don't.

Comment: Thanks!  I see what you are saying but in my case I have a bunch of one-D arrays (same length) that I have to average.  So that's why I thought to dump them all into jagged array in a loop (Simply do a[n] = b... where a is [][] and b is []).  And then average them using Accord .NET.  Perhaps you can suggest something better?  Thank you!